# Iccube - How to change height of items inside a Tree Filter using custom theme definition?

Tags: typescript, iccube, iccube-reporting

Using iccube reporting V8.2.2, I'm trying to change the height of items inside a Tree Filter using custom theme definition.

With following code in my theme definition TS file, I succeeded in changing the item height from 38px (default defined somewhere I don't know) to 22px :

```
FilterTree: {
    variants: [
        {
            props: {variant: 'My Own Tree'},
            style: {
                "&": 
                    {
                    ".ic3VirtualizedTreeItem-root": {
                        height: '22px !important',
                    }, ...
```

But this changes only the height of the item, not it's position, which seems to be calculated somewhere... and not using the new height I defined.

[image]

How can I define this top property for all the items correctly ? In this exemple, I want 44px (2 * 22) instead of 76px (2 * 38)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tree filter uses virtualization (using [react-window](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-window)), and thus needs a set height for each item in the tree. This cannot be done using CSS. For release 8.3.0, we plan to add an option in the theme, `theme.ic3.treeFilter.itemHeight`, which you can use to change the height of the items.